# has contains - how to get the text which is exist in html?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a text existance in the first element of my paragaraph. I am looking the result as `true` or `false` or significant result. but not working, the way i use this wrong here?

```js
var para = $('p:first')
var status = para.has(':contains(<br)');
console.log(status); //exist or not?
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>
<p>yes</p>
```

Comment: what is 'not working'?, be specific; and plz keep 'console' (`F12`) open while running code in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` selector searches only *in* the text, **not** **`HTML`**. You might use a simple `String.indexOf` for this purpose.

There are other ways of doing this, but this is most native and also efficient.

```
var status = para.html().indexOf("<br") > -1; // just a simple check
```